# How to print value in boost::u32regex & reg

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-regex

I want to print a value in `boost::u32regex & reg` using `std::cout`.

For `boost::regex & reg`, I can print `reg.str()` but not able to use `str()` to `boost::u32regex`.

Can anyone please tell me ?

Comment: Do you have a little piece of code, with a working example with `boost::regex` and another one not working with `boost::u32regex`. And do you have any error message ?

Comment: const char* er = "(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2}|\d{4})";
boost::regex rNormal( er );
std::cout << "Normal regular expression :" << rNormal.str() << std::endl;
boost::u32regex r = boost::make_u32regex("(?:\\A|.*\\\\)([^\\\\]+)");
   std::cout << "u32 regular expression :" << r.str() << std::endl;

Comment: You should edit you post with this sample. Did you read the answer I made ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the type used behind `boost::u32regex` is not compatible with `cout`. It seems they are using `Uchar32` from the `ICU` library.

You can print your regex value by using iterators :

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/regex/icu.hpp>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>

void PrintRegex32( const boost::u32regex& r )
{
    boost::u32regex::iterator it  = r.begin();
    boost::u32regex::iterator ite = r.end();

    for ( ; it != ite; ++it )
    {
        std::cout << UnicodeString(*it) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is working for me. It is not as easy as printing a `boost::regex` value but it works. I suggest you to create a function to do so, like in the example.

EDIT :

You can try the code :

```
boost::u32regex r = boost::make_u32regex("(?:\\A|.*\\\)([^\\\]+)");
PrintRegex32( r );
```

---

> *I can print `reg.str()`*

Just for the information, `boost::basic_regex` has an `operator<<` overload who are doing exactly the same thing so :

```
// reg is a boost::regex
std::cout << reg.str() << std::endl;
```

is the same thing as

```
// reg is a boost::regex
std::cout << reg << std::endl;
```

Comment: i am getting this error "template2.cc:11:29: error: invalid types âconst int[int]â for array subscript"

Comment: my compilation statement is "g++ -o template2 template2.cc -lboost_regex -licuuc -std=gnu++0x". anything need to be linked?

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud `UChar32` is a typedef of `int` on my (and, apparently, OP's) Linux, so `(*it)[0]` is an error. This needs ICU-compatible output.

Comment: @RayappanA If it is for debugging purpose, I edited my post with a solution. I just tried it and it works fine.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud still in my case it == ite, do i need to set any flag in compilation statement? my compilation statement is "g++ -o template2 template2.cc -lboost_regex -licuuc -licuio -std=gnu++0x" and OS is 64 bit ubuntu server version.

Comment: @RayappanA That's weird... For me it works like a charm... Just with your compilation line... But I'm not on a 64bit OS... Are you sure you do not enter in the loop ?